# Error: EROFS: read-only file system [MAC]

Tags: node.js, macos, sh

I have an npm project in location:

```
~/dev/project
```

**`npm run build`** runs this script `'sh devDependencies/runbuild.sh'`. Location of the script is here `~/dev/projectdevDependencies/runbuild.sh`. I'm running the script in `~/dev/project`.

`runbuild.sh` contents:

```
echo creating build/ folder
mkdir -m 0777 build 

echo copy /js/
cp -R js build/
chmod 0777 -R build/js

echo [changing rights] index.js
chmod 0777 build/js/index.js
    
browserify build/js/index.js -o /build/js/build.js
```

I get an error:

```
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/build'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:987:3)
    at sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/mkdirp-classic/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/mkdirp-classic/index.js:77:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js:64:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -30,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EROFS',
  path: '/build'
}
```

ls -l:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 sander  wheel  218175 Mar  9 14:28 bundle.js
-rw-r--r--  1 sander  wheel    7869 Mar  9 14:28 index.js
```

There are read and write access?

I have tried running the script in `/tmp` folder which gives the same result.

I have tried running as `sudo` which also gives same result.

I don't think I should run this command `csrutil disable` because that would be too extreme.

Where should I put my project so that I don't have this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
browserify build/js/index.js -o /build/js/build.js
```

You should not have `-o /build/js/`, because that points to entirely different place than `build/js/`.